# Using annotations to get a ChoiceList of Entity constatnts

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

Is it possible to use annotations to get a `ChoiceList` or `array` of specific type of class/entity constants?

I mean something like this:

```
class User{
    /**
     * @Item(Things,'Label 1')
     */
    const SOME_THING1=1;
    /**
     * @Item(Things,'Label 2')
     */
    const SOME_THING2=2;
    /**
     * @Item(Things,'Label 3')
     */
    const SOME_THING3=3;



    /**
     * @Item(OtherThings,'Label 1')
     */
    const SOME_OTHER_THING1=1;
    /**
     * @Item(OtherThings,'Label 2')
     */
    const SOME_OTHER_THING2=2;

    ...
}
```

and then:

```
$builder->add('thing', 'choice', array(
  'choice_list' => getChoiceListFromConsts('User','Things')
));
```

And I expect `getChoiceListFromConsts('User','Things')` to return something like:

```
array( 
     'Label 1' => 1,
     'Label 2' => 2,
     'Label 3' => 3
);
```

Is there a build-in feature for this in Symfony2 or is there any bundle that provide such a service?

Comment: No, not with annotations, but yes, with the `entity` form type and query builder.

Comment: @hcoat: And how with the entity form type and query builder?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. As I have looked over the question again, I thought of ways to get the values but it doesn't seem that they are the best solution, but then again I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @hcoat , i want to make further changes in  such fields easy and increase dynamicality; thanks anyway

Comment: @hcoat , i want to make further changes in  such fields easy and increase dynamicality; thanks anyway